# Feature files are not running in defined order on Selenium junit?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

### My Feature files:

**test.feature**
@Login
Feature: A Login Feature
  Verify if user is able to Login in to the site

Scenario Outline: Login as a authenticated user
 Given user is on homepage
   When user navigates to Login Page
   And  user enters "username" and "Password"
   Then success message is displayed

**logout.feature**
@Signout
Feature: Logout validations
    Verify if user is able to Login in to the site

Scenario: sce to logout validtaions
        When user is on PRR portal
    And user click signout button
    Then Home page should load

**My runner file**

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(

features = {"D:\ramesh\cucmbertest\src\main\java\features\test.feature","D:\ramesh\cucmbertest\src\main\java\features\Logout.feature"}
,glue= {"seleniumgluecode"},plugin = { "pretty", "html:src/cucumber-reports" },monochrome = true

)

public class testrunner {

}

My expectation is need to run "test.feature" then "logout.feature" , but logout is getting executed first. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Feature files are run in alphabetic order. Aint a good idea to depend on running order for tests.

Comment: is that any way to specify the order?! @Grasshopper